# Using the definition of a derivative, solve $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(2+h)^{3+h} - 8}{h}$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

I can't figure out where to even start, I have looked up the answer on Desmos but it uses L'Hopitals rule which i haven't learned yet.

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(2+h)^{3+h} - 8}{h}$$
I see that i can use the log rules to rewrite it as
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{(3+h)\ln(2+h)} - 8}{h}$$
but that only confuses me more.

Comment: it is h, sorry didn't notice that

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=x^{x+1}.$ Then the limit equals $f'(2)$.

Comment: @Levent So you're saying let $f(x) = x^{x+1}$ and then $ x = 2+h$, am I one the right path?

Comment: The definition of the derivative  at a point $x_0$ is that $f'(x_0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$. What do you get for the function $f(x)=x^{x+1}$ and $x_0=2?$

Comment: I get$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(2)+h} - f(2)}{h} $$which equal 1

Comment: $h$ is inside the function $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Levent's comment, supposed that you're given $f(x) = x^{x+1}$.  By definition of the derivative:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{(x+h)^{x+1+h} - x^{x+1}}{h}$$

Now, plug in $x=2$.

$$f'(2) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{(2+h)^{3+h} - 8}{h}$$

Hey, that's conveniently familiar!  Now your question can be rephrased as “Find $f'(2)$.”

Now, what's the derivative of $y = f(x) = x^{x+1}$?  The equation may be easier to work with if you take logarithms.

$$ \ln y = (x + 1) \ln x$$

You can then use implicit differentiation to get:

$$\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \ln x + \frac{x+1}{x} = \ln x + 1 + \frac{1}{x}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y(\ln x + 1 + \frac{1}{x})$$

And plugging in $x=2$ and $y=8$ gives:

$$f'(2) = 8(\ln 2 + 1 + \frac{1}{2}) = 8 \ln 2 + 12$$

Answer (score 1):

I follow up on your suggestion to use a logarithm. Define

$$ \phi(h)= e^{(3+h)\ln(2+h)}, \text{ noting that } \phi(0)= 8.$$

On the one hand, $$\phi'(0) \;=\; \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\phi(h)-\phi(0)}{h-0},$$ which is exactly your target.

But applying the basic rules for derivatives of complicated expressions:

$$ \phi'(h)= \phi(h)\left[\ln(2+h) + (3+h)\frac1{2+h}\right],$$

$$ \phi'(0)= 12+8\ln 2.$$